# explain recursive sum method

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala programming. I'm in functions topic.

```
def sumOfInts(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  if(a>b) 0 else a + sumOfInts(a+1,b)
}
println(sumOfInts(1,5)
```

The output of the program is 15, how it could be 15? Can anyone please explain how it got 15?

Comment: scala is functional programming language, in scala, recursion more often used,  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion-in-scala/ https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/tail_recursion

Comment: Why is 15 an unexpected output?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988 to understand why "Explain this code to me" type questions are not acceptable on [so], and what you can do to [edit] your question to improve it to acceptable standards. *Which parts, precisely* do you not understand? What *do* you understand? Do you understand that the sum of the integers from 1 to 15 is 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5? Do you understand why that is 15? Do you understand what a method is? Do you understand what a method call is? Do you understand what a conditional expression is? Without an explanation of what you do and do not …

Comment: … understand, answering the question would require multiple books.

Answer (score 3):

Let's walk through what happens when it is called.

First `sumOfInts` is called with a=1, b=5. `a` is not more than `b`, so we use the branch `a + sumOfInts(a+1,b)`. `a` is one 1, so we have `1 + sumOfInts(2, 5)`. Following this pattern we end up with

```
1 + 2 + sumOfInts(3,5)
1 + 2 + 3 + sumOfInts(4,5)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + sumOfInts(5,5)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + sumOfInts(6, 5)
```

Then with `a=6`, `a>b` is true, so `sumOfInts(6,5)` returns `0`. So the final call stack looks like:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 0
```

Which gives us 15.

Answer (score 2):

I'll lay it in a less dense manner and with line numbers, so it's easier to refer to them

```scala
1: def sumOfInts(a: Int, b: Int) = {
2:  if (a > b) {
3:    0
4:  } else {
5:    a + sumOfInts(a+1, b)
6:  }
}
```

If you take a closer look you'll see that `sumOfInts` calls itself - on line 5. This technique is called recursion - and you probably want to understand it well, as it is found in many algorithms, approaches and interview questions :) But simply put, recursion when a function does some calculation, calls itself with slightly modified parameters and then "merges" the result of the calculation with the result of self-call (called recursive call).

In this particular case all this "calculate, recurse, merge" happens on line 5:

- "Calculate" part is simply taking value of `a`,
- "recurse" - call `sumOfInts(a+1, b)`
- "merge" is taking a sum of above.

Now, in order to actually complete at some point, each recursive function must have two properties:

- the call arguments between "function you're executing just now" and recursive call must differ - in this case it the `a+1` that does so,
- there must be a condition to terminate the recursion - i.e. there should be a code path that **does not** cause the recursive call. In this case, it's the condition on line 1

Enough with the theory I think :) Let's just trace the function and see the result. I'm going to "substitute" the function calls iteratively - that's actually one of the techniques that compiler/runtime might employ to optimize the code, but even for humans it is very useful :)

```
1st call: a=1, b=5, a < b => 1 + sumOfInts(1+1, 5)
2nd call: a=2, b=5, a < b => 1 + 2 + sumOfInts(2+1, 5)
3rd call: a=3, b=5, a < b => 1 + 2 + 3 + sumOfInts(3+1, 5)
4th call: a=4, b=5, a < b => 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + sumOfInts(4+1, 5)
5th call: a=5, b=5, a = b => 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + sumOfInts(5+1, 5)
6th call: a=6, b=5, a > b => 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 0 = 15
```